# ASP.Net Core dotnet ef migration not creating Identity tables on server, while other custom tables are created

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I have a ASP.Net Core 2.2 C# application, using the Core Identity. I'm using code first, so when there are database-related changes in the code I use the dotnet ef migrations & update commands. I have extended the standard Core Identity and have added other custom tables, created in the C# code. Locally all the migrations worked perfect and everything is working fine.

Now I need to transfer the complete application to a server. I can't get the SQL database to create the Identity tables, using migrations & update. My other custom tables are created as expected.

This is what I tried:
1. Copy the complete project to the server
2. Create the needed SQL database instance
3. In Command-line execute: dotnet ef database update ==> Only custom tables where added, NO Identity tables
4. Remove all the migration files from the project
5. In Comamand-line execute: dotnet ef migrations add ServerCreate ==> In script creating of custom tables if visible, NO Identity tables
6. Just tried to "dotnet ef database update", but as expected NO Identity tables

Locally everything is working fine. How can I create a clean database code first with all the needed tables?

Any help would be great, I'm clueless .....

Comment: Might be a silly question but why do you copy the code to the server instead of executing the db-migrations on your dev-machine by applying the correct connection-string?

Comment: No silly question at all !!! This actually solved my problems, thanks for the advice Alsami